# How do I submit a form and get the content after that with phantom js?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to submit a form and after submit get the contents of the page.I tried to do:

```
      var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
console.log(msg);
 };
 page.open("http://www.mcservidores.com.br/login.php", function(status) {
if ( status === "success" ) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
          document.querySelector("input[name='username']").value = "myusername";
          document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value = "mypassword";
         document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").submit();

    });
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      page.render('colorwheel.png');
      phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must collect the form data BEFORE you submit the form, unless you are capturing it on the server. When a non-ajax form is submitted, the current page stops execution. A new page in then served.